# Questions about passport applications

Tags: passports, international-travel, us-citizens

Dumb question but when I applied for my passport (from last year 2018) on the application it asks where I am traveling to, I only put one country down (Thailand) as that was planned at that moment but this year I am traveling to a different country (Laos) "didn't think of going to Laos at the time applying for passport." So my question is since I didn't mention (Laos) on my application does it matter or it doesn't matter as long as I have my passport? I didn't want any complication during my flight. I hope my question is understandable.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you applying for a passport or for a visa? Are you a citizen of the country where the passport will be issued?  Without knowing the issuing country, it is difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: I have a passport and is a citizen in the USA. I am just a little concern because when I applied for my passport I only put down traveling to Thailand and did not mention about Laos. I was worried if Laos was never mention in the application will there be any complication during my flight to Laos.

Answer (score 4):

A US passport, like most passports, is valid for all countries, whatever country you wrote you were going to on your application.

You may also need a visa for the country you are going to. Check the immigration rules for that country.

Comment: OMG! Thank you for answering! I was so worried! =D

Comment: @user91583 It's perfectly valid to leave that blank, as well. You aren't required to have travel plans to obtain or renew a passport, unless you're applying for expedited service precisely because you have imminent travel plans. Also the passport is valid for travel anywhere, not just the country you might have listed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you so much for clarifying it! Appreciated!